# NodeJS query processing results design pattern avoid nested then statements

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, design-patterns

I am writing an application in NodeJS10 and Mongoose5. I am writing a custom server-side pagination function. I want to run the pagination in a controller for separation of concerns and reusability.

I have a query to get data and return it in a then() response handler. I am then calling the custom pagination function inside the then() handler. This works, but I am concerned about the "nested" then/catch patterns. I think this might be messy especially if there is any additional processing required on the data before returning the response.

Here is the "nested" structure. How can I improve this to make it no longer nested and more readable while still catching all possible errors and returning the response correctly? Note that this *works* just fine, it's just the design pattern is messy and I want to avoid the "nested" then() statements if possible.

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  const origin = 'routes/items.js GET /:id';

  const id = req.params.id;

  items.find({
    _id: id
  }).then(data => {

    uiCtrl.pagination(data, req.query).then((result) => {
      res.status(200).send(result);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(`pagination failed ${error}`);
      res.status(500).send(`pagination failed ${error}`);
    });

  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(`${origin} ${error}`);
    res.status(404).send('Not found');
  });

});
```

Here is the custom async function being called inside the query result above.

```
const uiCtrl = {};

uiCtrl.pagination = async (data, query) => {

  // pagination logic here
  return data;
}

module.exports = uiCtrl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rewrite using normal `async/await` stuff:

```
var data, results;
try {
   data = await items.find({_id:id}).toArray();
}
catch (err) {
   console.log(`${origin} ${error}`);
   res.status(404).send('Not found');
}
try {
   results = await uiCtrl.pagination(data, req.query);    
}
catch (err) {
   console.error(`pagination failed ${error}`);
   res.status(500).send(`pagination failed ${error}`);
}
```

It should be noted that given the fact that I know nothing more of your code than what I can see, there are probably some other things you can do that will make the code better to read and easier to use (ie rejecting a promise and doing something meaningful with it instead of throwing exceptions).  You would also need to have all this code wrapped in an `async` method so you can the `await` keyword.

**EDIT**

For completion's sake given the full code now I would start by rewriting it something like this:

```
router.get('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  const origin = 'routes/items.js GET /:id';

  const id = req.params.id;

  var itemResults, paginationResults;
  try {
     itemResults = await items.find({_id: id}).toArray();
  }
  catch (err) {
     console.log(`${origin} ${error}`);
     res.status(404).send('Not found');
  }
  try {
     paginationResults = await uiCtrl.pagination(data, req.query);
     res.status(200).send(result);
  }
  catch (err) {
     console.error(`pagination failed ${error}`);
     res.status(500).send(`pagination failed ${error}`);
  }
});
```

One other thing I would do as a sort of optimization or housekeeping thing would be to move the error catching into a single `catch` block and parse the error out there to make things more concise.

Also including this as it talks about something called `callback hell` which is very relevant to the information you are asking about.

http://callbackhell.com/

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question to include the entire example. The "nested" part is just inside of a router.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reworked solution based on the accepted answer. I was getting this error, I think this is due to placing the 'async' keyword directly in the router definition e.g. `router.get('/', async (req, res, next)`. Perhaps because in this format it is not handled with then or catch.

`(node:3564) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3564) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

I ended up with a slightly modified solution, I made a wrapper function and called it with a then() handler. Thanks!

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const origin = 'routes/items.js GET /';

    async function queryWrapper() {
        let data, results;

        try {
          data = await items.find();
          console.log(`data ${data}`);
        }
        catch (err) {
          console.log(`${origin} ${err}`);
        }
        try {
          results = await uiCtrl.pagination(data, req.query);
        }
        catch (err) {
          console.error(`pagination failed ${err}`);
        }

        if (results) {
          return results;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }

      queryWrapper().then((result) => {
        res.status(200).send(result);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(`${error}`);
        res.status(500).send(`${error}`);
      });
});
```